# It's great vs this is great vs that is great

Tags: exclamatives

> There are too many hotels in our city. **It's great!**

Or this is great ?

Or that is great ?

What is the best to say here?
When does we say each ?

Thank you

Comment: All three are idiomatic, although it's hard to see what is good about having too many hotels.

Comment: Thank you, so are they interchangeable with no difference at all ?

Comment: Yes, there is no difference among _"It's great!", "This is great!",_ and _"That's great!"_ However, can you tell us why it is good to have too many hotels?

Comment: Thank you for answering, I just copied a sentence, (the one that has written this sentence asks us to grammaticaly correct it - I do not find any grammatical error in it). So there is no context there. However,for me it is well understood to mean that because there are all these hotels there in my city, it is good for my city tourism or for people to have various places to visit and have fun.

Comment: You should learn that the expression _too many_ is negative in most cases. The sense of the adjectival in your sentence is that fewer hotels would be better. This makes the succeeding sentence confusing to a native speaker, since something that is not desirable is seldom described as "great".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a slight difference in your three sayings

> **It's great**!

can be used for something *nonspecific*, could be anything.

> **This is great**!

is used when speaking of something *specific* which may be *closer* to the speaker.  The previous two are the closest in meaning of the three.

> **That is great**!

is spoken about something which is **further away** from the speaker.

Often "**That is great!**" is used as a response (*further away from the situation*) to someone saying "**It's great!**" or "**This is great!**" (*closer to the situation*).

If you tell someone

> There are too many hotels in our city. **It's great**!

you will probably get the response

> Yes, **that's great**!

except from @P.E.Dant...

Comment: Thank  you for your response but what do you mean by something closer or further away from the speaker? Could you explain this further please?

Comment: If you say, "It's great *(for me)*, I got a discounted airline ticket." that is *closer* to you since it effects you, for your friend, it is *further away* since it doesn't  effect him.  He might respond by saying "Yes that is great *(for you)*!" with the *for you* being implied.

Comment: Do you really not believe that the OP should know that the phrase _too many_ is not a positive? Surely it is not better that he later embarrass himself by exclaiming: _"We have too many cars. This is great!"_

Comment: My thought was that in this instance saying "We have too many hotels" implies greater competition and better pricing for hotel users.  Actually car dealers do exclaim "We have too many cars, and we have to get rid of them. This is great *for you*!"  :)